# How to optimize Gauss-Seidel routine in C++ for sparse matrices?

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, numerical-methods

I've written a routine in C++ that solves the system of equations Ax = b using Gauss-Seidel method. However, I want to use this code for specific "A" matrices that are sparse (most of the elements are zero). This way, most of the time that this solver takes is busy multiplying some elements by zero.

For example, for the following system of equations:

```
| 4 -1  0  0  0 | | x1 |   | b1 |
|-1  4 -1  0  0 | | x2 |   | b2 |
| 0 -1  4 -1  0 | | x3 | = | b3 |
| 0  0 -1  4 -1 | | x4 |   | b4 |
| 0  0  0 -1  4 | | x5 |   | b5 |
```

Using Gauss-Seidel method, we will have the following iteration formula for x1:

x1 = [b1 - (-1 * x2 + 0 * x3 + 0 * x4 + 0 * x5)] / 4

As you see, the solver is wasting time by multiplying zero elements. Since I work with big matrices (for example, 10^5 by 10^5), this will influence the total CPU time in a negative way. I wonder if there is a way to optimize the solver so that it omits those part of calculations related to zero element multiplications.

Note that the the form of the "A" matrix in the example above is arbitrary and the solver must be able to work with any "A" matrix.

Here is the code:

```
void GaussSeidel(double **A, double *b, double *x, int arraySize)
{   
const double tol = 0.001 * arraySize;
double error = tol + 1;

for (int i = 1; i <= arraySize; ++i)
    x[i] = 0;

double *xOld;
xOld = new double [arraySize];
for (int i = 1; i <= arraySize; ++i)
    xOld[i] = 101;

while (abs(error) > tol)
{

    for (int i = 1; i <= arraySize; ++i)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j <= arraySize; ++j)
        {
            if (j == i)
                continue;
            sum = sum + A[i][j] * x[j];
        }
        x[i] = 1 / A[i][i] * (b[i] - sum);
    }

    //cout << endl << "Answers:" << endl << endl;
    error = errorCalc(xOld, x, arraySize);

    for (int i = 1; i <= arraySize; ++i)
        xOld[i] = x[i];

cout << "Solution converged!" << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible unless you change the data structure. Are you sure beforehand that the matrix will be tridiagonal and not just "sparse"?

Comment: The matrix is just sparse and not necessarily tridiagonal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How sparse do you mean?

Here's a crappy sparse implementation that should work well for solving systems of linear equasions.  It's probably a naive implementation, I know very little about the data structures typically used in industrial strength sparse matrices.

[The code, and an example, is here.](http://ideone.com/LHkkmQ)

Here's the class that does most of the work:

```
template <typename T>
class SparseMatrix
{
private:
    SparseMatrix();

public:
    SparseMatrix(int row, int col);

    T Get(int row, int col) const;
    void Put(int row, int col, T value);

    int GetRowCount() const;
    int GetColCount() const;

    static void GaussSeidelLinearSolve(const SparseMatrix<T>& A, const SparseMatrix<T>& B, SparseMatrix<T>& X);

private:
    int dim_row;
    int dim_col;

    vector<map<int, T> > values_by_row;
    vector<map<int, T> > values_by_col;
};
```

The other method definitions are included in the ideone.  I don't test for convergence, but rather simply loop an arbitrary number of times.

The sparse representation stores, by row and column, the positions of all of the values, using STL maps.  I'm able to solve a system of 10000 equasions in just 1/4 seconds for a very sparse matrix like the one you provided (density < .001).

My implementation should be generic enough to support any integral or user defined type that supports comparison, the 4 arithmetic operators (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`), and that can be explicitly cast from 0 (empty nodes are given the value `(T) 0`).

Comment: In addition, I suspect that there are additional restrictions on the behavior of the templated type (specifically, some behaviors may cause the system to fail to converge).  In general, any type whose domain is isomorphic to the real numbers should work.

Comment: I didn't think to mention this before, but you should be careful - this implementation will perform very poorly for non-sparse matrices.

Answer (score 4):

Writing a sparse linear system solver is hard. **VERY HARD.**

I would just pick one of the exisiting implementations. Any reasonable LP solver has a sparse linear system solver inside, see for example [lp_solve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/), [GLPK](http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/), etc.

If the licence is acceptable for you, I recommend the [Harwell Subroutine library](http://www.hsl.rl.ac.uk/). Interfacing C++ and Fortran is not fun though...

Comment: Why is it hard. Could you elaborate, please. I'm going to implement it anyway, so i would like to know gotchas beforehand. Thanks.

Comment: @Yola Sorry, I cannot elaborate it in a comment. Read the book [Direct methods for sparse matrices](http://amzn.com/0198534213) by Duff, Erisman, Reid if you want to know the gotchas.

Comment: It is not hard at all. In Gauss-Seidel, you just need to go through each row of the matrix, from left to right. Represent a sparse matrix as CSR (extremely simple). The time complexity will correspond to the number of non-zero entries. I made it all (CSR + Gauss-Seidel on it) in 35 lines of code.

Comment: @IvanKuckir Maybe, if all you need is a sparse Gauss-Seidel method and nothing else. But chances are that you will need more, and then you will end up writing your own sparse linear algebra library. And I don't think Gauss-Seidel is the right choice for large, sparse matrices, but maybe I am wrong. My statement is: "Writing a sparse linear system solver is hard", and I still think it is true.

Comment: @Ali you can not just say something without explaining why do you think so. By LP, do you mean linear programming? The "linear system solver" includes the solver for linear programming in your case? Large systems of linear equations are hard to solve analytically (in a cubic time), so iterative methods are used to approximate the solution. These methods usually go through each row / column, and the existing data structures for sparse matrices do not make it any harder.

Comment: @IvanKuckir [I did link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665276/how-to-optimize-gauss-seidel-routine-in-c-for-sparse-matrices/15666972?noredirect=1#comment73700512_15666972) to the book on Direct methods for sparse matrices why I say so. Do you want me to copy a book chapter here? *"Large systems of linear equations are hard to solve analytically (in a cubic time), so iterative methods are used to approximate the solution."* And direct methods, the ones that I linked, they run in linear time. I am not sure iterative method are the right choice.

Comment: @IvanKuckir And as I said: If all you need is a sparse Gauss-Seidel method and nothing else, then maybe you can get away with what you are suggesting. In practice, I highly doubt that you will stop there. Sooner or later you will need scaling, preconditioner, etc., and then you are just writing your own sparse linear algebra library. And I am not convinced that iterative methods are the right choice for this task. With a sparse linear algebra library you can easily test different methods, compare direct and iterative ones, and pick the one that suits the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I face the same problem.
My solution is using vector array to save the sparse matrix.
Here is my code:

```
#define PRECISION   0.01

inline bool checkPricision(float x[], float pre[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (fabs(x[i] - pre[i]) > PRECISION) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/* mx = b */
void gaussIteration(std::vector< std::pair<int, float> >* m, float x[], float b[], int n) {
    float* pre = new float[n];
    int cnt = 0;
    while (true) {
        cnt++;
        memcpy(pre, x, sizeof(float)* n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            x[i] = b[i];
            float mii = -1;
            for (int j = 0; j < m[i].size(); j++) {
                if (m[i][j].first != i) {
                    x[i] -= m[i][j].second * x[m[i][j].first];
                }
                else {
                    mii = m[i][j].second;
                }
            }
            if (mii == -1) {
                puts("Error: No Solution");
                return;
            }
            x[i] /= mii;
        }
        if (checkPricision(x, pre, n)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    delete[] pre;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try PETSC. You need CRS (Compressed row storage) format for this.